# Returning 2 lines based on 1st and last entries

Tags: sql, teradata

I am trying to pull 2 lines per USERID, the first line being with the oldest date(RSLVD_DTTM), the second being with the lastest(RSLVD_DTTM)

Here is what I currently have

```
USERID  VIRTUAL_PROFILE            LINE_STABILITY numb1  numb2     RSLVD_DTTM

USER1  STGR_al2_d7296-1184_u1088-256    STABLE  "7,296" "20,074"    12/06/2012  
USER1  STGR_al1_d12288-5056_u1088-256   STABLE  "12,284""21,700"    08/01/2013  
USER1  STGR_al1_d7296-1184_u1088-256    STABLE  "7,292" "21,479"    06/11/2012  
USER1  STGR_al1_d7296-1184_u1088-256    STABLE  "7,292" "20,365"    03/04/2012
```

HERE is a example of what I want the output to be.

```
USERID  VIRTUAL_PROFILE LINE_STABILITY_RATING    numb1    numb2     RSLVD_DTTM
USER1   STGR_al1_d7296-1184_u1088-256   STABLE  "7,292" "20,365"    03/04/2012  
USER1   STGR_al1_d12288-5056_u1088-256  STABLE  "12,284""21,700     08/01/2013
```

HERE is my query

```
select 
  USERID,
  VIRTUAL_PROFILE, 
  LINE_STABILITY_RATING,
  numb1,
  numb2,
  RSLVD_DTTM
from 
  symmktg.V_NDW_ACTUAL_SPEEDS, symmktg.VREMEDY_SYM_TICKET
where 
   USERID IS IN ('USER1')
   and cast(RSLVD_DTTM as date) = '2013/03/23'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to add more information about what in those two rows is important. I can't see anything that would indicate why you'd want to select only those two rows.

Comment: I want to select those rows because of RSLVD_DTTM, I want it to pull the dates from the oldest entries to the newest entires... nothing in between.

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it

Comment: Hey, Im quite new to this fiel. It is TERADATA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the window function `row_number()` for this:

```
select USERID,VIRTUAL_PROFILE, LINE_STABILITY_RATING,numb1,numb2,RSLVD_DTTM
from (select USERID,VIRTUAL_PROFILE, LINE_STABILITY_RATING,numb1,numb2,RSLVD_DTTM,
             row_number() over (partition by userId order by rslvd_dttm asc) as seqnuma,
             row_number() over (partition by userId order by rslvd_dttm desc) as seqnumd
      from symmktg.V_NDW_ACTUAL_SPEEDS, symmktg.VREMEDY_SYM_TICKET
      where USERID IS IN ('USER1') and cast(RSLVD_DTTM as date) = '2013/03/23' 
     ) t
where seqnuma = 1 or seqnumd = 1
```

Most databases support this function.

By the way, I do not understand your query. The join condition should be using modern join syntax rather than a `,`.

Comment: +1 "I do not understand your query." (me neither!). -1 "The join condition should be using modern syntax..." (which authority?). +1 Nice solution. 1-1+1=1. :-)

Comment: Im using TeraData, I seem to be getting an error. Would this be suitable for teradata?

Comment: @ErrolGreen . . . What kind of error.  Teradata definitely supports `row_number()`.  `is in` is an unual construct; normally this is just `in`.  I did have an extra comma in the subquery, but that is now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The following query will get only the oldest and newest records for the given user:

```
select userid,
       virtual_profile,
       line_stability_rating,
       numb1,
       numb2,
       rslvd_dttm
from 
   symmktg.v_ndw_actual_speeds, 
   symmktg.vremedy_sym_ticket

where 
   userid in ('user1')
   and (rslvd_dttm = (select min(rslvd_dttm) 
                      from symmktg.v_ndw_actual_speeds, symmktg.vremedy_sym_ticket
                      where userid in ('user1'))
    or  (rslvd_dttm = (select max(rslvd_dttm) 
                       from symmktg.v_ndw_actual_speeds, symmktg.vremedy_sym_ticket)
                       where userid in ('user1'))
```

Comment: -1 I think you need to group by user in both your sub queries? Correct me if I'm wrong and I'll remove downvote. Would it be better to do one lot of aggregation, rather than doing it twice in two sub queries? Or would the DBMS likely prefer two separate result sets to join, rather than my solution than joins on an OR, do you think? Ie given your rep, I am genuinely interested in your opinions.

Comment: @Sepster - Filtering in the sub-queries is sufficient. There's no need to group since there is only one value being selected. As for the performance difference between the two, I'm not sure which one would be preferable. You'd have to profile and see.

Comment: I didn't realise that it was valid syntax, even though it does make logical sense. I'll propose a small edit to your post as I can't remove my downvote until its edited, sorry. Thanks for setting me straight!

Answer (score 0):

Your query doesn't tell us your table definitions, ie which column comes from which table.

It also looks like you're using a cross join, which means you're getting a result set with no clear relationship between the fields from each table. This may be intentional, but I doubt it. I would expect some kind of primary/foreign key relationship between your two tables, such that for each row in one table, there's a number of corresponding rows from the other. Currently, for each row in one table, you're returning *every* row from the other.

So I think this is the general pattern you're after, using more modern (and explicitly clear) Ansi92 syntax:

```
  Select 
    t.your-return-values, 
    ..., 
    o.your-other-return-values, 
    ...

  From
    Sourcetable t

    Inner join yourothertable o 
    on o.somekey = t.somekey

    Inner join
    (
       Select UserId, min(rslvd_dttm) as mindttm, max(rsvld_dttm) as maxdttm
       From sourcetable
       Group by userid

    ) q
    On t.userid = q.userid 
    and (t.rslvd_dttm = q.mindttm or t.rslvd_dttm = q.maxdttm)
```

However you'll need to establish what field from one table is related to what field in the other, I'm order to specify your keys for that first join.

Also, the join is currently INNER, meaning it will only return results from the first table, if at least one corresponding result exists in the second.

You may want to change it to LEFT, meaning a row containing the values from the first table is returned, even if no matching rows from the second could be found (in which case those columns are returned null for that row).

If you need this in the Ansi89 syntax you were using, let me know and I'll see what I can do!

Answer (score 0):

As some others already told you there's no real join condition between both tables.

Adding to Gordon Linoff's solution:

1. you might use QUALIFY instead of a Derived Table in Teradata
2. two ROW_NUMBERs with different ORDER BY will result in two step for calculation, when you rewrite it with MAX/MIN it's only a single step

This will result in

```
select 
  USERID,
  VIRTUAL_PROFILE, 
  LINE_STABILITY_RATING,
  numb1,
  numb2,
  RSLVD_DTTM
from 
  symmktg.V_NDW_ACTUAL_SPEEDS, symmktg.VREMEDY_SYM_TICKET
where 
   USERID IS IN ('USER1')
   and cast(RSLVD_DTTM as date) = '2013/03/23'
qualify 
   min() over (partition by userId) = RSLVD_DTTM
or max() over (partition by userId) = RSLVD_DTTM
```